# os.path.basename() is inconsistent and I'm not sure why

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

While creating a program that backs up my files, I found that os.path.basename() was not working consistently. For example:

```
import os

folder = '\\\\server\\studies\\backup\\backup_files'
os.path.basename(folder)
```

returns `'backup_files'`

```
folder = '\\\\server\\studies'
os.path.basename(folder)
```

returns `''`

I want that second basename function to return 'studies' but it returns an empty string. I ran `os.path.split(folder)` to see how it's splitting the string and it turns out it's considering the entire path to be the directory, i.e. `('\\\\server\\studies', ' ')`.

I can't figure out how to get around it.. The weirdest thing is I ran the same line earlier and it worked, but it won't anymore! Does it have something to do with the very first part being a shared folder on the network drive?

Comment: Take a look at [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

that looks like a Windows UNC specificity

UNC paths can be seen as equivalent of unix path, only with double backslashes at the start.

A workaround would be to use classical `rsplit`:

```
>>> r"\\server\studies".rsplit(os.sep,1)[-1]
'studies'
```

Fun fact: with 3 paths it works properly:

```
>>> os.path.basename(r"\\a\b\c")
'c'
```

Now why this? let's check the source code of `ntpath` on windows:

```
def basename(p):
    """Returns the final component of a pathname"""
    return split(p)[1]
```

okay now `split`

```
def split(p):
    seps = _get_bothseps(p)
    d, p = splitdrive(p)
```

now `splitdrive`

```
def splitdrive(p):
    """Split a pathname into drive/UNC sharepoint and relative path specifiers.
    Returns a 2-tuple (drive_or_unc, path); either part may be empty.
```

Just reading the documentation makes us understand what's going on.

A Windows sharepoint has to contain 2 path parts:

```
\\server\shareroot
```

So `\\server\studies` is seen as the drive, and the path is empty. Doesn't happen when there are 3 parts in the path.

Note that it's not a bug, since it's not possible to use `\\server` like a normal directory, create dirs below, etc...

Note that the official documentation for [`os.path.basename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) doesn't mention that (because `os.path` calls `ntpath` behind the scenes) but it states:

> Return the base name of pathname path. This is the second element of the pair returned by passing path to the function split(). **Note that the result of this function is different from the Unix basename program**

That last emphasised part at least is true! (and the documentation for [`os.path.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.split) doesn't mention that issue or even talks about windows)